# I can SSH into server, but HTTP doesn't work at all?

Tags: nginx, centos-7

I set up **`nginx`** everything has been working grand for a couple months until today I noticed that I **couldn't connect to my website**. I can :

- SSH into my server
- Service `nginx` status confirms that it is `Running`
- Domain name points to the IP correctly.

I'm at loss of how to further diagnose this issue and any assistance would be greatly appreciated !

Edit:

Thanks for the suggestions guys! I'm still unclear as to how this issue arose, but I've been able to resolve it with firewall-cmd. Specifically by adding http & https services:

```
firewall-cmd --add-service=http --permanent 
firewall-cmd --add-service=https --permanent
```

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Please consider adding more details as to What OS, distribution, server version you are using ? What have you tried, any commands or log outputs ? Any other details that may help out to solve the issue. This way you would get better answers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To narrow this down...

1. Confirm Nginx is actually running.  Look at the process list `ps -ax | grep nginx`
2. Confirm Nginx is actually listening on the port you expect (`80`?).  https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/106561/5313
3. Ensure that you can access Nginx from the host itself.  That is, SSH in, use `curl -v http://localhost`, if Nginx is configured to listen on any address.  Then, verify the public IPs that Nginx is supposed to listen on, again from the host itself `curl -v http://[your address here]`.
4. Check to see if you can access Nginx externally, directly by IP address.  Chances are this is where the failure is.
5. Verify that your firewall (whatever software, hardware, or combination firewalls you're using) allows access to Nginx.
6. Verify that the DNS entry pointing to your server is resolving correctly.

Comment: Hi Brad - 1, 2 and 3 all pass without a hitch. I've tried the server's IP address in my web browser to port 80 and 443 on my computer using my internet connection and on my phone's 4g connection (Hopefully this rules out a firewall issue?). Pinging my server's domain name gives me the correct IP address and I am currently SSHing to that domain name too. Any ideas? Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: @JayY - rather then rule out the issue, it points to the problem being a firewall issue.